# Terraform 403 error using Azure DevOps self-hosted agent

Tags: azure, azure-devops

We currently have a Azure DevOps pipeline that deploys and maintains our infrastructure. We provision and maintain using Terraform.

All of the resources are integrated in a virtual network, this includes the storage accounts. The storage accounts have the subnets whitelisted and all of the resources can access the storage without issues.

We have been having trouble deploying new resources or even just running terraform plan due to 403 errors that occur while trying to refresh the state of the containers.

At first we used an az cli task that whitelisted the Azure provided DevOps agent, however as of lately that didn't work anymore as the 403 kept coming.

We deployed a Ubuntu VM and configured with the required packages; pwsh, az cli, terraform etc.. The NIC associated with the VM has been integrated in the subnet as our other VM's, this subnet is whitelisted from the storage.
However, we still get the same 403 errors as before, even now the VM is in the same vnet and the subnet is whitelisted.

I am trying to think of other possible solutions, perhaps any of you know how we can solve this. Thank you.

We tried to integrate a self-hosted Azure DevOps agent into our virtual network to be able to run our infrastructure as code pipelines to provision and maintain resources. However we keep getting 403 unauthorized errors.

Comment: When you directly run the same terraform script  on the Ubuntu VM local env, will it work fine or have the same issue?

Comment: Hello Kevin, 
I have done the test, just executing the terraform script on the Ubuntu VM local env plans without problem. So no 403 errors.

Comment: When you run the terraform plan in pipeline, can you check if the service connection is valid. Make sure that the service connection is not expired.

Comment: Hi Kevin, The same service connection was used while running manually on the VM, the same credentials were used in the ARM_CLIENT_ID ARM_CLIENT_SECRET environment variables. It is not expired.